# Display image while uploading

Tags: php, file-upload

I have asked this question before,but I didn't get real solution for this.I am developing a social website.In the user registration page,user has the provision to add a photo.My problem is that I want to display the image which has been uploaded by the user to a div,before clicking the submit button at the end of the form.I have searched a lot,but couldn't get the right one.

My html code is like this:

```
 <img src="<?php echo $row_picture;?>" name="picture" class="settingspic"  width="75" height="91" alt="profile pic" name="picture"/><a href="" onclick="return uploadimg()"> Upload</a></li>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="display:none;" />
```

My javascript code is:

```
function uploadimg()
{
 var uploader = document.getElementById('file');
 uploader.click();
 return false;
}
```

When I click the submit button,image is inserted in the database.I want the image to be displayed when the user upload the file.

Comment: Upload the file. Save it to some place temporary (the DB will work) and set it to the image `src`. When the use clicks "OK", save it to the final location and update the `src` to the final resource.

Comment: If you need to show the image while uploading, I think you will need some Flash script for that. Otherwise I don't think you can access local file using javascript to show it.

Comment: Actually it seems I am wrong. There is some example code in this link. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/  It uses html5.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'm using on our site. This is for previewing the image before upload, i.e. before submitting the form. Your question is a little bit different but I hope this could help.

**HTML:**

```
<img id="preview_img" style="max-width: 130px; max-height: 130px;" src="http://www.domain.com/images/<?php echo $this->profile_details->photo? $this->profile_details->photo: "default.png"; ?>"/>
<input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#preview_img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```